# How to extract the 9 images from following image without text?

Tags: image, image-processing

[This image is DNA sequence visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGvfG.png)

Comment: I just want to say this image is a part from original one. the original one contain more than 3000 DNA sequence images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't like the command-line approach, I have recast my **ImageMagick** answer in **Python**. I am quite a beginner in **Python** so there may be inefficiencies and poor practices in my code, but it works. The technique is exactly the same as the other answer:

- convert to HSV colourspace, and locate highly saturated (coloured) pixels,
- run `label()` from **skimage** to do *"Connected Component"* labelling,
- extract blobs and save as files.

---

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from skimage import color
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops

# Load image and convert to RGB discarding any alpha
im=np.array(Image.open('dna.png').convert('RGB'))

# Add 1px black border all around so shapes don't touch edges
blackcanvas=np.zeros((im.shape[0]+2,im.shape[1]+2,3))
blackcanvas[1:-1,1:-1]=im
im=blackcanvas

# Convert to HSV colourspace, discard H, V and find saturated (i.e. brightly coloured) pixels
HSV=color.rgb2hsv(im)
S=HSV[:,:,1]
bw=(S>0.5)*255

# Image is now white blobs on black background, so label() it
label_image=label(bw)

# Iterate through blobs, saving each to disk
i=0
for region in regionprops(label_image):
   if region.area >= 100:
      # Extract rectangle containing blob and save
      name="blob-" + str(i) + ".png"
      minr, minc, maxr, maxc = region.bbox
      Image.fromarray(im[minr:maxr,minc:maxc,:].astype(np.uint8)).save(name)
      i = i + 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

It can be done at the command-line in Terminal. So, first we want to identify the areas that are images and reject the text. The easiest thing is to make all saturated colours white and all grey/unsaturated colours black:

```
convert dna.png -fx "saturation<0.5? 0 : 1" z.jpg
```

[image]

Now we can do *"Blob Analysis"* or *"Connected Component Analysis"* to find the white *"blobs"* like this:

```
convert dna.png -fx "saturation<0.5? 0 : 1"       \
    -define connected-components:verbose=true     \
    -connected-components 8 -auto-level output.png
```

**Sample Output**

```
Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 314x112+0+0 155.2,56.1 28249 srgba(0,0,0,2.31991)
  3: 100x16+214+23 262.9,30.4 1576 srgba(255,255,255,42.5831)
  2: 100x16+108+23 157.1,30.1 1511 srgba(255,255,255,44.3719)
  9: 100x8+2+88 50.4,91.4 777 srgba(255,255,255,85.3436)       <--- THIS ONE
  6: 100x7+2+55 50.7,57.9 687 srgba(255,255,255,96.393)
  1: 100x6+2+23 50.5,25.4 587 srgba(255,255,255,112.644)
  10: 100x6+108+96 156.9,98.0 507 srgba(255,255,255,130.26)
  7: 100x5+108+65 155.6,66.9 477 srgba(255,255,255,138.39)
  8: 100x5+214+65 263.3,66.5 399 srgba(255,255,255,165.248)
  11: 100x5+214+96 263.2,97.5 396 srgba(255,255,255,166.492)
  5: 1x1+110+33 110.0,33.0 1 srgba(0,0,0,65535)
  4: 1x1+200+27 200.0,27.0 1 srgba(0,0,0,65535)
```

There is a heading/title line then one line for each blob found in the image. Let's look at the line:

```
 9: 100x8+2+88 50.4,91.4 777 srgba(255,255,255,85.3436)
```

That means there is a blob 100x8 pixels in size at offset (2,88) from the top-left corner. Let's fill it in semi-transparent red:

```
 convert dna.png -stroke red -fill "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)" -draw "rectangle 2,88 102,96" p.png
```

[image]

And let's crop it out into a new image:

```
convert dna.png -crop 100x8+2+88 +repage result.png
```

[image]

A little `awk` script will get the other blobs for you.