# How to embed a small photo in the center of a larger black background in python?

Tags: python, image

So, I have a collection of binary (black and white) photos with the heights and the widths varying from 80px to 140px. The aspect ratio is not fixed. I want to embed each photo in the center of a larger 150px × 150px photo in Python.

I have only recently become familiar with PIL and OpenCV. And I haven't been coding in Python for long. Hence, I'm stuck. Any solution that works in Python is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as review [ask].  In it's current form, this questions is much too broad for SO.  Provide your code, show what's going wrong, then someone might be able to help you.

Comment: @user3483203  What part of it is too broad? The language is Python. The question is to embed a matrix of size m &times; m in a larger n &times; n matrix where n/2 - 1 <= m/2 <= n/2 + 1. The problem seems very specific and well-defined to me.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing or tutorial service.  Please provide the code that you have written to solve this problem, and also share the problems that you have had with the code that you have written.  Also review the links I shared above.

Comment: Look at the two lines starting `blackcanvas = ...` here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51964270/2836621 That loads an image, creates a black canvas 1px bigger on each side and pastes the loaded image in offset 1px left and ine pixel down from the top-left... exactly what you want with slightly different  maths.

Comment: @user3483203 Neither did I say it was a code-writing or a tutorial service. I have seen questions like this asked before. And some of them were upvoted too. I do not know where to start. As I said, I'm stuck. Everyone has to start from somewhere. It just happens that my knowledge of Python is not enough for tackling this problem as of yet.

Comment: @MarkSetchell  Thanks for your answer. If I understand correctly, I have to find the maximum height and width and then use the trick on that post to enlargen the pictures. Am I right?

Comment: Yep, more or less. See if you can do it, and I'll check tomorrow and help out if you get stuck - it's getting late here now.

Comment: You don't need OpenCV for that at all. The offset for `x` is `(150-imagewidth)/2` and for `y` is `(150-imageheight)2`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell  Yes, you're right. Thank you for all your help. I'm trying to write the code now. I will edit my post after I'm done. Please check it tomorrow if you had time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done something very similar before using PIL. I'm assuming you're trying to output the new image.

```
from PIL import Image

# load in the top image
top_img = Image.open('1.jpg', 'r')
top_img_w, top_img_h = top_img.size

# load in the bottom image
bottom_img = Image.open('2.jpg', 'r')
# get the size or use 150x150 if it's constant
bottom_img_w, bottom_img_h = bottom_img.size

# offset the top image so it's placed in the middle of the bottom image
offset = ((bottom_img_w - top_img_w) // 2, (bottom_img_h - top_img_h) // 2)

# embed top_img on top of bottom_img
bottom_img.paste(top_img, offset)

output_name = '3.jpg'
bottom_img.save(output_name)
```

Comment: That looks good - maybe you could adapt it a little closer to OP's request for a 150x150 black background using `canvas = Image.new("RGB",(150,150),(0,0,0))` instead of reading in `2.jpg`...

Comment: Thanks, Alex. This was really helpful. The "paste" method is what I was looking for. Also, thank you @MarkSetchell